# Error Upgrading SharePoint Products

Tags: sharepoint-server, upgrade

I installed the last CU (October 2020).
Our SysAdmin used to upgrade the system by using the psconfig.exe and always used the -force flag, which in my opition is not the best way to do it.
This time I wanted to try to use the wizard, which fails on the step 9 of 10: Upgrading SharePoint Products.

In the event log I find:

```
Application Server Administration job failed for service instance Microsoft.Office.Server.Search.Administration.SearchServiceInstance (d250035e-48e4-402b-8818-1eb515ed35af).
Reason: ActivatingTopology information could not be fetched from SearchTopologyActivationInfo.
Technical Support Details:
System.InvalidOperationException: ActivatingTopology information could not be fetched from SearchTopologyActivationInfo.
   at Microsoft.Office.Server.Search.Administration.SearchServiceInstance.Synchronize()
   at Microsoft.Office.Server.Administration.ApplicationServerJob.ProvisionLocalSharedServiceInstances(Boolean isAdministrationServiceJob)
```

The ULS says:

```
Topology Rollback failed. Will try again. Meanwhile, topology activation will not be possible: System.InvalidOperationException: ActivatingTopology information could not be fetched from SearchTopologyActivationInfo.    
 at Microsoft.Office.Server.Search.Administration.Topology.SearchTopology.Rollback()    
 at Microsoft.Office.Server.Search.Administration.Topology.SearchTopology.RetryPendingRollback()    
 at Microsoft.Office.Server.Search.Administration.SearchServiceInstance.Synchronize()
Unable to find server 45929293-42f0-4b79-8857-4cd6e20cb0f7
Application Server Administration job failed for service instance Microsoft.Office.Server.Search.Administration.SearchServiceInstance (d250035e-48e4-402b-8818-1eb515ed35af).  Reason: ActivatingTopology information could not be fetched from SearchTopologyActivationInfo.  Technical Support Details: System.InvalidOperationException: ActivatingTopology information could not be fetched from SearchTopologyActivationInfo.    
 at Microsoft.Office.Server.Search.Administration.SearchServiceInstance.Synchronize()    
 at Microsoft.Office.Server.Administration.ApplicationServerJob.ProvisionLocalSharedServiceInstances(Boolean isAdministrationServiceJob)
```

Any idea about the problem?

Answer (score 0):

Please Clear the configuration cache on front end servers.

You can refer to the article below:

[Clear configuration cache in SharePoint farm 2010 , 2013](http://sharepointviews.com/clear-configuration-cache-in-sharepoint-farm-2010-2013/)

Comment: Hi, already done but did not help.